# Crontab won't run automatically

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu, cron

I have setup a cron job as shown below but it won't run. When I run the script manually, I don't see any errors.

```
#_____WPR Jobs
00 9 * * * mon-sat /var/spool/ftpexts/bin/exe_get_x_wpr.sh >> /var/spool/ftpexts/outboundlogs/exe_get_x_wpr.log
00 9 * * * mon-sat /var/spool/ftpexts/bin/exe_get_y_wpr.sh >> /var/spool/ftpexts/outboundlogs/exe_get_y_wpr.log
00 9 * * * mon-sat /var/spool/ftpexts/bin/exe_get_z_wpr.sh >> /var/spool/ftpexts/outboundlogs/exe_get_z_wpr.log
```

When I execute the script manually as shown below, it runs smoothly with log records too.

```
/var/spool/ftpexts/bin/exe_get_x_wpr.sh >> /var/spool/ftpexts/outboundlogs/exe_get_x_wpr.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crontab` is trying to execute `mon-sat` as a command.

The day of the week is specified as the 5th field of a crontab entry. You have `*`, which means it runs on any day of the week. Delete that 5th field, making `mon-sat` the 5th field. (Interesting, I didn't know until now that crontab would recognize names.)

UPDATE: The [crontab(5) man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) (type `man 5 crontab` to read it on your system) says:

> Names can also be used for the "month" and "day of week" fields. Use
>   the first three letters of the particular day or month (case doesn't
>   matter). Ranges or lists of names are not allowed.

You say that `mon-sat` worked for you. A quick experiment indicates that ranges of names actually do work, but since the documentation says they're not allowed, I suggest not depending on that. Write `1-6` rather than `mon-sat` if you want the job to run Monday through Saturday.

Comment: This support for names instead of numbers seems to be a Vixie feature, and isn't a POSIX feature. Solaris and AIX don't support it, NetBSD, FreeBSD, and Linux do. Also, the RedHat man page for crontab(5) says __`Ranges or lists of names are not allowed`__, so this would technically still be wrong.

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname: Thanks, I had missed that. I'll do some tests to confirm how it really works and update my answer.

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname: Looks like it does work, but the man page says it's not allowed, so I wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: I'm never sure whether to have a positive or negative opinion of software that does things like that.

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname: Agreed. But perhaps the documentation is just out of sync with the software. One could study the history of the software and the man page to see when and whether they diverged. (I'd do so if I cared.)